# What SQL command to use to filter concatenated string?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to create a SQL command that can sort through a concatenated string in my database it is listed at.

Colors: blue,red,green,yellow

```
SELECT * FROM `shoes` WHERE CONCAT(',',color,',') LIKE '%,blue,red%'
```

How do I filter the data where it can come up with shoes that are available in red or blue or red and blue and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix your data structure.  The proper way to store a list of things in a database in a relational database is to use tables.  In particular, you need a junction tale.

That said, sometimes one is stuck with substandard designs.  In MySQL, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set('blue', colors) > 0 and find_in_set('red', colors) > 0
```

This would get rows where shows are available in both red and blue.

Comment: I could have a table of shoe colors? trouble is how do i ensure that shoes that come in multiple colors are picked up?